# Does this construction define a ring and if so what properties does it have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, grothendieck-construction

Let $a \oplus b := \gcd(a,b)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{N_0}$.
Starting from the observation that for each $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N_0}$ we have:

$$a \gcd(b,c) = \gcd(ab,ac)$$

we might translate this to  the distributive law:

$$a \cdot (b \oplus c) = (a\cdot b) \oplus (a\cdot c)$$

The set $\mathbb{N_0}$ with $\oplus$ forms a commutative monoid and we might construct its Grothendieck-Group.
Setting 
$$[(a,b)]\times [(c,d)] := [(ac \oplus bd, ad \oplus bc)]$$
and 
$$[(a,b)] \oplus [(c,d)] := [(a \oplus c, b \oplus d)]$$

my question is, if this makes the Grothendieck-Group to a ring?
If so, what properties does this ring have? Can we further localize the non-zero elements of this ring to make it to a field?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For any $a,b$, $a \oplus 1 = b \oplus 1$; therefore, the Grothendieck group would collapse to the trivial group.

Comment: ok thats the point here. thanks

Comment: That said, in general any time you have a semiring as you did here, its Grothendieck group will indeed form a ring via the construction you described.